# Remove the certain properties of objects from the json document response Swagger for REST api

Tags: swagger

Hi I am using swagger for documentation of my RESTful web service.  wanted to know is there any way to remove the certain properties of objects from the json document response? I mean there are lots of properties that swagger gives for my method param objects and response model (e.g. notes, defaultValue, allowableValue, internalDescription etc.) that are not required for me and are null due to that the response is not much readable

For method params:

```
     "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "someName1",
                        "description": null,
                        "notes": null,
                        "paramType": "path",
                        "defaultValue": null,
                        "allowableValues": null,
                        "required": true,
                        "allowMultiple": false,
                        "paramAccess": null,
                        "internalDescription": null,
                        "wrapperName": null,
                        "dataType": "string",
                        "valueTypeInternal": null
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "someName2",
                        "description": null,
                        "notes": null,
                        "paramType": "query",
                        "defaultValue": null,
                        "allowableValues": null,
                        "required": true,
                        "allowMultiple": false,
                        "paramAccess": null,
                        "internalDescription": null,
                        "wrapperName": null,
                        "dataType": "string",
                        "valueTypeInternal": null
                    }
                ],
```

-=============================================================================

For response model classes

```
"SomeResponseClass": {
        "required": false,
        "name": null,
        "id": "SomeResponseClass",
        "properties": {
            "instanceVariable1": {
                "required": false,
                "name": null,
                "id": null,
                "properties": null,
                "allowableValues": null,
                "description": null,
                "notes": null,
                "access": null,
                "default": null,
                "additionalProperties": null,
                "items": null,
                "uniqueItems": false,
                "type": "Date"
            },
            "instanceVariable2": {
                "required": false,
                "name": null,
                "id": null,
                "properties": null,
                "allowableValues": null,
                "description": null,
                "notes": null,
                "access": null,
                "default": null,
                "additionalProperties": null,
                "items": null,
                "uniqueItems": false,
                "type": "double"
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

your JSON mapper is not configured to ignore null properties.  You can easily address this as follows:

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JacksonJsonProvider extends JacksonJaxbJsonProvider {
private static ObjectMapper commonMapper = null;

public JacksonJsonProvider() {
    if(commonMapper == null){
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT);
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

        commonMapper = mapper;
    }
    super.setMapper(commonMapper);
    }
}
```

Add this mapper to your scanning properties in the web.xml and the nulls will be gone.